# Download a file from HDFS cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am developing an API for using hdfs as a distributed file storage. I have made a REST api for allowing a server to mkdir, ls, create and delete a file in the HDFS cluster using Webhdfs. But since Webhdfs does not support downloading a file, are there any solutions for achieving this. I mean I have a server who runs my REST api and communicates with the cluster. I know the OPEN operation just supports reading a text file content, but suppose I have a file which is 300 MB in size, how can I download it from the hdfs cluster. Do you guys have any possible solutions.? I was thinking of directly pinging the datanodes for a file, but this solution is flawed as if the file is 300 MB in size, it will put a huge load on my proxy server, so is there a streaming API to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you could make use of `streamFile` provided by DataNode API.

```
wget http://$datanode:50075/streamFile/demofile.txt
```

It'll not read the file as a whole, so the burden will be low, IMHO. I have tried it, but on a pseudo setup and it works fine. You can just give it a try on your fully distributed setup and see if it helps.

Comment: Hmm, this looks interesting, let me give it a try

Comment: Also, I had a question, which is very different from my original question, I want to get the data node on which the file is located, how do you suppose I get that.

Comment: Easiest way would be to point your web browser to HDFS webUI, i.e "namemnode_machine:50070"..Then browse to the file in question and click to open it. Scroll down and you can see the location of each block of this file.

Comment: Hmm, that indeed is an easy way, but is it possible to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can use "getFileBlockLocations(FileStatus file, long start, long len)" provided by "FileSystem". It return an array containing hostnames, offset and size of portions of the given file.

Answer (score 0):

One way which comes to my mind, is to use a proxy worker, which reads the file using hadoop file system API, and creates a local normal file.And the provide download link to this file. Downside being

1. Scalablity of Proxy server
2. Files may be theoretically too large to fit into disk of a single proxy server.

Comment: True, this is a good idea, but scalability will be problematic, so I believe streaming the file can be a good idea, and by streaming I mean breaking the file up into chunks and then sending it to the client.